# Get available time slots for appointment booking using Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to develop an API for scheduling appointments for several salons.

Right now I have models and serializers for the `Salon` and the `Appointment`. All appointments can have different durations. The `Appointment` model looks like this:

```
    class Appointment(models.Model):
        date = models.DateField()
        start_time = models.TimeField()
        end_time = models.TimeField()

        salon = models.ForeignKey(Salon, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

How can I return all salons and their available time slots (no appointment at that time) for a given date.
So say if a salon is open from 10:00-16:00 and has only one appointment from 11:00-11:30 we would get something like:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "My Salon",
    "city": "London",

    "time_slots": [
        {
            "date": "2019-12-01",
            "start_time": "10:00:00",
            "end_time": "11:00:00",
        },
        {
            "date": "2019-12-01",
            "start_time": "11:30:00",
            "end_time": "16:00:00",
        }
    ]
}
```

Right now the only way I can think of is by adding a new `TimeSlot` model with `Salon` as Foreign key and saving all time slots in the database and changing them once an appointment is made? However, this does not seem very efficient.

Is there a better way of calculating and returning the time slots?

Edit

Serializers:

```
class AppointmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('id', 'date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'salon')

class SalonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    appointment_set = AppointmentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Salon
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'city', 'appointment_set')
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Can you share your serializers?

Comment: @funnydman Edited. We assume all salons are open at the same time for now, I have not added the logic for this yet.

Comment: your code is correct. This should give expected result. Are you getting any error.

Comment: @sandeep No, I am not getting errors. I just want to know a good way to get the times when there are no appointments for each salon.

Comment: you mean times when slots are not created or time slots created but not booked. If case 1, you need time for 24 hrs or there is time period for salons like 10am - 9pm

Comment: @sandeep I need time slots that are not booked basically. They are not created yet. Is there a way to just calculate when they are and not save them in the database? Like go through all appointments and calculate the gaps between them? Not sure how I can add it to the serializer though.

Comment: @Imaginary can you show `Salon` model code?

Comment: @funnydman the Salon model only has the name and city fields, since I am using a one to many relationship (salon - appointments)

Comment: @Imaginaryy so, where the data about from which time a salon is open stored then?

Comment: I think you should create a time slot field in Salon model. Salon owner will be able to create time slots as per their requirement.

Comment: Also, you can add a boolian field in Appointement model ( booked_status).you can check booked_status and find out available slots for specific or all salons.

Comment: @sandeep Yes this might be the better solution, thank you! But when should these time slots be created, because they have to be in every day? Also do you mean keeping the number of time slots or having a separate model for them?